# How i can get the position of the HTML document with scrollTop ()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I want to get the position of the document and display it in console in px with jQuery scrollTop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must calculate the distance of scrollbar from the top point.

**http://jsfiddle.net/6hcE7/1/**

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should just be:

```
console.log(jQuery(document).scrollTop());
```